# Get Json array that equals the value of $stateParam

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm having trouble in fetching specific array in details page. $stateParams needs to be the same with the JSON array id but I can't print that on its template. I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Services**

```
angular.module('demo', ['ui.router']);
.factory('BookService', ['$http', function($http){
  return {list: $http.get('data.json')}
}])
```

**Routes**

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/books');
    $stateProvider
        .state('books', {
            url:'/books',
            templateUrl: 'templates/books.html',
            controller: 'BooksCtrl'
        })
        .state('books.detail', {
            url: '/detail/:id',
            templateUrl: 'templates/books-detail.html',
            controller: 'BooksDetailCtrl'
        });
}])
```

**Controllers**

```
.controller('BooksCtrl', ['$scope', 'BookService', function($scope, BookService){
  BookService.list
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.books = data;
    });
}])
.controller('BooksDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'BookService',
function($scope, $stateParams, BookService){
    $scope.selectedBook = BookService.find(BookService.list, $stateParams.id);
}])
```

**JSON File(data.json)**

```
    {   "demo_site": [{
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Demo 1",
            "summary": "Summary 1",
            "body": "test demo 1",
            "image": "img/compress/placehold.jpg",
            "source": "angular/source",
            "demo_link": "http://github.com"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Demo 2",
            "summary": "Summary 2",
            "body": "test demo 2",
            "image": "img/compress/placehold.jpg",
            "source": "angular/source",
            "demo_link": "http://github.com"
        }]
}
```

Templates
*books.html*

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-action="selected" ng-repeat="book in books.demo_site">
    <a ui-sref="books.detail({id: book.id})">{{ book.title }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="detail" ui-view></div>
```

*books-detail.html*

```
<div>
    {{selectedBook.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code a bit and it works now. The most important change is mocking the BookService by bookServiceMock (I added it because I don't have access to your service).

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/books');
    $stateProvider
        .state('books', {
            url:'/books',
            templateUrl: 'books.html',
            controller: 'BooksCtrl'
        })
        .state('books.detail', {
            url: '/detail/:id',
            templateUrl: 'books-detail.html',
            controller: 'BooksDetailCtrl'
        });
}]);

app.service('bookServiceMock', function() {
  var books =[{
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Demo 1",
            "summary": "Summary 1",
            "body": "test demo 1",
            "image": "img/compress/placehold.jpg",
            "source": "angular/source",
            "demo_link": "http://github.com"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Demo 2",
            "summary": "Summary 2",
            "body": "test demo 2",
            "image": "img/compress/placehold.jpg",
            "source": "angular/source",
            "demo_link": "http://github.com"
        }];

  this.getBooks = function() {
    return books;
  };

  this.getBook = function(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
      if (books[i].id === id) {
        return books[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
})

app.controller('BooksCtrl', ['$scope', 'bookServiceMock',  function($scope, bookServiceMock){
    console.log('BooksCtrl');
        $scope.books =  bookServiceMock.getBooks();
}]);

app.controller('BooksDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'bookServiceMock',
function($scope, $stateParams, bookServiceMock){
  $scope.selectedBook = bookServiceMock.getBook($stateParams.id);
}]);
```

books.html

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-action="selected" ng-repeat="book in books">
    <a ui-sref="books.detail({id: book.id})">{{ book.title }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="detail" ui-view></div>
```

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VJxlqguJZGrIutAFLCNc

Comment: Thanks @Michał it helps me a lot but I was try to fetch json data in separate file and trying to test how to make it work.  It'll be great if you can share example. Thanks again